# Using TABLESAMPLE with PERCENT returns all the records from table

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive

I have a small ***test*** table with two fields - ***id*** and **name**, 19 records total. When I try to get 10 percent of record from this table using the following query, I get ALL the records. I tried to do this on large table, but result is the same - all records are returned. The query:

```
select * from test tablesample (10 percent) s;
```

If I use ROWS instead of TABLESAMPLE (i.e.: `select * from test tablesample (10 rows) s;`, it works fine, only 10 records are returned. How can I get just the neccessary percentage of records?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the link below:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Sampling

You must be using CombinedHiveOutputFormat, which does not go well with ORC format. Hence you will never be able to save the output from Percent query to a table.

In my knowledge the best way to do this is using rand() function. But again you should not use this with order by() clause as it will impact performance. Here is my sample query which is time efficient :

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE rand() <= 0.0001
DISTRIBUTE BY rand()
SORT BY rand()
LIMIT 5000;
```

I tested this on 900M row table and query executed in 2 mins.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PERCENT` with `TABLESAMPLE`. For example:

```
SELECT * FR0M TABLE_NAME
TABLESAMPLE(1 PERCENT) T;
```

This will select 1% of the data size of inputs and not necessarily the number of rows. More details can be found [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Sampling).

But if you are really looking for a method to select a percentage of the number of rows, then you may have to use `LIMIT` clause with the number of records you need to retrieve.

For example, if your table has 1000 records, then you can select random 10% records as:

```
select * from table_name order by rand() limit 100;
```

Comment: I do, as you have described in first case, but it doesn't work - ALL records are returned. The second way is not useful for me - I do not know the number of records in main table, thus I can't select 10% from it.

Comment: Could you add the version details?

Comment: And are you getting all the records for the small test table (19 records)? In that case, it could be that all the records are in the same block. I would suggest testing it out on a bigger table.

Comment: Hive version - 0.11.0.2

Comment: Ok. PERCENT is supported from 0.8 above and so it's not the problem.

Comment: I've got records from both small table and large table. All records were fetched in both cases.

Comment: From https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Sampling#LanguageManualSampling-BlockSampling:
"Only CombineHiveInputFormat is supported and some special compression formats are not handled. If we fail to sample it, the input of MapReduce job will be the whole table/partition."